# Choosing StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget for sub-widget which has TextEditingController as a child

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

I'm working on a refactored code to separated small piece of widgets.
There's several columns with `TextFields` in each one of them.I have two options to complete the task :

1. Choosing `StatelessWidget` since it have **more performance**, may put TextEditingController related code outside of sub widgets. Or include some logic in `onChanged` event. but still there's some events like `clear text` can't put in `onChanged` event
2. Choosing `StatefulWidget` if I use `TextEditingController` include inside each sub widget.

**How to choose between `StatelessWidget` and `StatefulWidget` when refactoring code into small widgets like this ?**

---

Update

Here's my current conclusion which can be updated if it's not correct.

- Prefer to put `FocusNode` of `TextEdit`in parent since it's related to brother focusNode & parentNode;
- Prefer to put `TextEdtingController` in parent, which will be useful in cases like when `TextField` is out of screen like a `ListItem` scrolled out of the screen, which will make the whole widget unmounted. The state will be preserved.
- Preferring to put `animation self` like shaking `TextField` when inputting something wrong in self. Since it's a feature of the `TextField` not related to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit in response to the discussion in the comments section:

You should go with the second approach when refactoring your code into smaller `StatefulWidgets`. And the `parent` should have a function to alter the nested  TextFields' content and its `animation` behavior by calling functions inside it, as you earlier indicated you need to manage this behavior.

Comment: What about clear text logic, which more like the sub widget’s feature self, to implement it I include TextEditingController which need StafulWidget

Comment: And animation part I currently have a global animation to control TextField, after refactor, I can use StatefulWidget’s property for all of them, but  what about animation which more like TextField self feature, to include animation controller , still need use Stateful Widget.

Comment: @JerryZhou I guess you need to make to `parent` `StatefulWidget` too, since it's the only way to alter its state using `clear()`. And for the animation part of the `TextField`, again you're right. I guess my answer need a revision.

Comment: Another way is to put most of static UI in with const when possible even in StatefulWidget to improve performance

Comment: Using `const` may cause problems sometimes, I remember one question here where someone was complaining about a strange in its `build` function. Turned out to be solved by eliminating `const`.

Comment: for clear() function , you prefer use only one TextEdtingController in parent widget then use as many as Textfield in each to controller it self?

Comment: You say linking all of them with one `TextEditingController` ?

Comment: ah , no, I mean put all  TextEdtingControllers together in one parent widget

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193922/discussion-between-mazin-ibrahim-and-jerryzhou).